# What parts do I need to build a iPhone

Tags: iphone, hardware, customization

I'm soon planning to build a iPhone 6, but before ordering random parts, I've made a list of parts needed to have an nice overview.

A list of what parts are needed:

- Housing
- LCD Screen + digitizer
- Motherboard
- Battery
- Volume button flex
- Power button flex
- Home button + flex
- Volume, Power and Home button spacers
- Vibration motor
- Audio and Dock connector
- Front camera, sensor + flex
- Back camera
- GPS

Am I missing some parts for the build? I so, can you please let me know. Is there maybe a list of the iPhone parts somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)
Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here. We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks. - From Review

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'd be able to build one from scratch using totally new parts, but you may find this [iPhone 6 teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+6+Teardown/29213) useful.

Comment: I think it's possible if you buy an 100% working recycled motherboard. From there you need to build and get the needed parts together. I can't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: I'm sure it would. I just meant you wouldn't be able to get totally new parts - well, not unless you bought a new iPhone 6, which would kind of defeat the purpose. :)

Comment: Let me clarify my last comment - you'd be able to get new parts - I just mean you wouldn't be able to get _all_ the parts brand new.

Comment: I understand now haha, I am thinking to buy the parts from AliExpress.